# Pass the details of Multiple rows from JSP to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a List of Employees in my JSP file, and for each employee, I have provided an option to update the location(drop-down). The results are passed on to the "SaveTubeDetails" servlet, which takes care of saving the data.

Here's the code I'm using currently:

```
<form action="SaveTubeDetails" method="POST">
 <table>
 <% 
   for(Iterator<Employee> itr = employeeArr.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){ 
   Employee emp= itr.next();
 %> 

<tr> 
  <td>
  <select name="location">
  <% for(int count=0; count<locArr.size(); count++){ %>     
  <option value="<%= locArr.get(count) %>" ><%= locArr.get(count) %></option>   
  <%} %>
  </select>
  </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My Question is, how do I get it saved as a List of Employees which can be passed on to the Servlet?

*Note: i'm not using Spring and Hibernate. And I know that scriptlets shoudn't be used, but I'm left with no choice as I'm updating the existing code. And although there's only the Location details of Employee shown here, actually there are more columns like Age, DOB, etc.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular example, all submitted values are as a string array available by [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29), in the exact same order as the inputs appear in the HTML markup.

```
String[] location = request.getParameterValues("location");
// ...
```

As an alternative, you might want to consider to include the employee ID in the input name so that any potential race conditions will be avoided (e.g. when an employee has been deleted from DB by a different enduser in between displaying the form and processing the form submit):

```html
<select name="location_<%=emp.getId()%>">
```

which can then be collected in the servlet based on an existing list of employees as follows:

```
List<Employee> employees = employeeService.list();

for (Employee employee : employees) {
    String location = request.getParameter("location_" + employee.getId());
    // ...
}
```